# convert multiline string to array in specific order

Tags: php

I have an string output which I would like to convert to an array in a particular order. I know what I need it to look like but unsure how to organize the array to suit my needs.

Here is the string output -- note: there may be more or less entries of "**Signed Certificate Timestamp:**" - in this example there are 3 of them. I have also manually added in `\n` to show you where the line breaks are which need to be all one one line when converted into the array as values.

```
Signed Certificate Timestamp:
    Version   : v1(0)
    Log ID    : A4:B9:09:90:B4:18:58:14:87:BB:13:A2:CC:67:70:0A:\n
                3C:35:98:04:F9:1B:DF:B8:E3:77:CD:0E:C8:0D:DC:10\n
    Timestamp : Jan 30 17:05:01.387 2015 GMT
    Extensions: none
    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                30:45:02:21:00:DE:07:C0:BC:5D:A8:96:93:73:EF:30:\n
                A2:4B:2F:8F:9C:D1:EB:DD:3B:05:23:B9:04:53:1A:16:\n
                64:CE:B8:EC:D8:02:20:66:AA:0C:E5:13:FE:99:E9:A9:\n
                D9:45:9D:C1:88:4C:B4:2C:47:78:87:55:95:2D:3D:1D:\n
                14:1D:2A:E2:F9:26:2C
Signed Certificate Timestamp:
    Version   : v1(0)
    Log ID    : 56:14:06:9A:2F:D7:C2:EC:D3:F5:E1:BD:44:B2:3E:C7:\n
                46:76:B9:BC:99:11:5C:C0:EF:94:98:55:D6:89:D0:DD\n
    Timestamp : Jan 30 17:05:02.013 2015 GMT
    Extensions: none
    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                30:45:02:20:2D:0C:CD:C7:13:BD:1D:1C:F1:F5:3E:B3:\n
                E3:B6:8D:8D:CF:DE:60:56:24:16:FF:AB:88:7C:29:E4:\n
                75:DB:D3:A1:02:21:00:C2:05:4A:88:5C:C8:69:11:FB:\n
                44:E3:C6:E1:7F:10:FD:7F:27:69:83:CD:6D:4E:E2:74:\n
                97:F3:B7:AB:4B:84:C9
Signed Certificate Timestamp:
    Version   : v1(0)
    Log ID    : 68:F6:98:F8:1F:64:82:BE:3A:8C:EE:B9:28:1D:4C:FC:\n
                71:51:5D:67:93:D4:44:D1:0A:67:AC:BB:4F:4F:FB:C4\n
    Timestamp : Jan 30 17:05:01.387 2015 GMT
    Extensions: none
    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                30:45:02:21:00:C3:EE:DF:09:0D:43:74:FC:B3:81:14:\n
                01:E5:38:9E:1E:2F:98:D2:3F:DF:EB:4E:62:71:C5:80:\n
                F6:8E:8D:9C:95:02:20:1D:EB:FA:0C:44:65:A8:6F:61:\n
                78:4C:58:97:88:19:A2:E0:47:60:B8:3A:13:6E:59:FF:\n
                F1:3D:5D:F5:B6:AB:F3
```

Here is how I would like the array to be organized

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Version] => v1(0)
            [Log ID] => A4:B9:09:90:B4:18:58:14:87:BB:13:A2:CC:67:70:0A:3C:35:98:04:F9:1B:DF:B8:E3:77:CD:0E:C8:0D:DC:10
            [Timestamp] => Jan 30 17:05:01.387 2015 GMT
            [Extensions] => none
            [Signature] => ecdsa-with-SHA256 30:45:02:21:00:DE:07:C0:BC:5D:A8:96:93:73:EF:30:A2:4B:2F:8F:9C:D1:EB:DD:3B:05:23:B9:04:53:1A:16:64:CE:B8:EC:D8:02:20:66:AA:0C:E5:13:FE:99:E9:A9:D9:45:9D:C1:88:4C:B4:2C:47:78:87:55:95:2D:3D:1D:14:1D:2A:E2:F9:26:2C
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Version] => v1(0)
            [Log ID] => 56:14:06:9A:2F:D7:C2:EC:D3:F5:E1:BD:44:B2:3E:C7:46:76:B9:BC:99:11:5C:C0:EF:94:98:55:D6:89:D0:DD
            [Timestamp] => Jan 30 17:05:02.013 2015 GMT
            [Extensions] => none
            [Signature] => ecdsa-with-SHA256 30:45:02:20:2D:0C:CD:C7:13:BD:1D:1C:F1:F5:3E:B3:E3:B6:8D:8D:CF:DE:60:56:24:16:FF:AB:88:7C:29:E4:75:DB:D3:A1:02:21:00:C2:05:4A:88:5C:C8:69:11:FB:44:E3:C6:E1:7F:10:FD:7F:27:69:83:CD:6D:4E:E2:74:97:F3:B7:AB:4B:84:C9
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Version] => v1(0)
            [Log ID] => 68:F6:98:F8:1F:64:82:BE:3A:8C:EE:B9:28:1D:4C:FC:71:51:5D:67:93:D4:44:D1:0A:67:AC:BB:4F:4F:FB:C4
            [Timestamp] => Jan 30 17:05:01.387 2015 GMT
            [Extensions] => none
            [Signature] => ecdsa-with-SHA256 30:45:02:21:00:C3:EE:DF:09:0D:43:74:FC:B3:81:14:01:E5:38:9E:1E:2F:98:D2:3F:DF:EB:4E:62:71:C5:80:F6:8E:8D:9C:95:02:20:1D:EB:FA:0C:44:65:A8:6F:61:78:4C:58:97:88:19:A2:E0:47:60:B8:3A:13:6E:59:FF:F1:3D:5D:F5:B6:AB:F3
        )
)
```

Comment: Something like this might be a start: https://eval.in/577296

Comment: yes, good start but seems to stop after second iteration where as there are 3 entries.. any ideas?

Comment: Updated: https://eval.in/577300

Comment: thank you. works perfectly now!